# Getting id from a textarea in a while loop in PHP for updating in mysql

Tags: php, css

I have a table where is one week displayed (each row is one day).
I get the rows from a while loop from my database. The rows are displayed in bootstrap accordions.
There is a textarea in every accordion row where the user can input (update) some text.

I want to update this text into my database. It should update the text depending on the day id.

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <table class="table table-hover" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th>Weekday</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
// Select Statement (for shortening not included into this Stack question)//

    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    $thedate = $row['Date'];
    $weekday=strftime("%A", strtotime($thedate));
    $date=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($thedate));

        echo "<tr data-toggle='collapse' data-target=#".$row['Date']." class='clickable collapse-row collapsed'>";
        echo "<td >".$weekday."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$date."</td>";
        echo" <td style='color:black; font-size:20px;'><i class='fas fa-angle-down'></i></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr><div class='accordian-body collapse' id=".$row['Date'].">
<td colspan='1' class='hiddenRow'><textarea name=".$row['id']." rows='5' cols='80'>".$row['Text']." </textarea></td>

//the $row['id'] should give every textarea a unique dayid from my database

echo"</td>
</div></tr>";
}
    if(ISSET($_POST['id'])){
    $debug=$_POST['id'];
    }
var_dump($debug); // var_dump for debugging. See text below

        ?>
</tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="Speichern" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Speichern</button>
    </form>
```

Before writing the Sql Update Statement I wanted to debug to find possible bugs.

If i debug this with var_dump I get the error message "Undefined variable $debug" and I dont know why. The variable shouldnt be empty because in the textareas is always text.
Im new to PHP and coding at all so probably Im making a dump mistake.

**EDIT**: If I put the var_dump inside the if condition i get nothing as return.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? And how is this related to CSS?

Comment: I want $debug to be an array with the text from the textarea and the id. But if i want to display $debug i get the  error message "Undefined variable $debug".

Comment: _“If i debug this with var_dump I get the error message "Undefined variable $debug" and I dont know why.”_ - because you are only creating the variable inside the condition that checks whether $_POST['id'] is set, but then you try to make the debug output with var_dump independent of that condition. So if the POST parameter was not set, you are trying to output the value of a variable you did not actually set either.

Comment: And what have you tried to check **why** this happens? I would assume that `$debug` is not defined unless you define it in the `if` branch

Comment: @CBroe Ok i understand. And how can i set this variable? I thought its set when i press the submit button.

Comment: Just move the var_dump _into_ the if block. _“I thought its set when i press the submit button.”_ - and, was that the case, when you initially loaded the page? No, it wasn’t, you did not submit any form to load the page in the first place, that was just a simple GET request.

Comment: @CBroe I tried it also with the var_dump in the if block but then i get nothing as return.

Comment: That’s because you do not have any form field that is actually named `id`. You put `name=".$row['id']."` on your textarea, and that is likely a numeric value. And you probably don’t know which one that will be, on the receiving end. Plus, since you are creating multiple such fields in a loop, PHP will overwrite all values for this parameter with the last one. You need to use a naming scheme that includes square brackets to avoid that, something like `name="foo[]"` - then `$_POST['foo']` will become an array that you can loop over.

Comment: And since you will still need your record ID to associate with the data, you can put that into the brackets, `name="foo[123]"` – then this `123` will become the key of that array element, for this specific textarea.

Comment: @CBroe Ok now i understand. If you want to write the last twocomments as an answer  I will accept it as the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried it also with the var_dump in the if block but then i get nothing as return.

That’s because you do not have any form field that is actually named `id`. You put `name=".$row['id']."` on your textarea, and that is likely a numeric value. And you probably don’t know which one that will be, on the receiving end.

Plus, since you are creating multiple such fields in a loop, PHP will overwrite all values for this parameter with the last one. You need to use a naming scheme that includes square brackets to avoid that, something like `name="foo[]"` - then `$_POST['foo']` will become an array that you can loop over.

And since you will still need your record ID to associate with the data, you can put that into the brackets, `name="foo[123]"` – then this `123` will become the key of that array element, for this specific textarea.

If you loop over that using the extended foreach syntax, then you have easy access to the ID, and the value entered by the user:

```
foreach( $_POST['foo'] as $id => $value ) { … }
```